# EPiServer 9: Is there any real alternative for EPiServer ContentArea Contents?

Tags: c#, asp.net, episerver

I am a beginner regarding EPiServer. We use EPiServer Version 9.12. 
EPiServer.Core.ContentArea had a Contents list in the past which is now obsolete, see: http://world.episerver.com/documentation/Class-library/?documentId=cms/7.5/284B326A

[image http://jweschenfelder.de/download/Untitled.png](http://jweschenfelder.de/download/Untitled.png)

The Contents list had the advantage in the past that you could read the name of the block because it read the full content of the ContentArea. It would be great to retrieve the name since you can configure it inside the CMS if you create a new block there. If I use the now suggested Items collection instead, I am not able to read the name of the block which contains the Link items collection, I am only able to read the Link items collection inside of the block then.

I have seen the example:
`IContentLoader contentLoader = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance< IContentLoader >();
OnSiteLinkBlock itemBlock = contentLoader.Get(item.ContentLink, new LoaderOptions() { LanguageLoaderOption.MasterLanguage() });`
I am able to edit OnSiteLinkBlock, but additional properties remain null and are not filled by the ContentLoader of the EPiServer (IContentLoader is an interface of EPiServer).

More info about the class hierarchy:
 - `[AvailableContentTypes(Availability = Availability.None)]
  public class BlockData : ContentData, IReadOnly< BlockData >, IReadOnly` (in EPiServer.Core)
 - `public abstract class BlockBase : BlockData` (BlockBase is an own class)
 
 - `public class OnSiteLinkBlock : BlockBase` (OnSiteLinkBlock is an own class)

Does someone know a solution here? How can I read more properties of the ContentArea? Or does exist an alternative for ContentArea? Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried without `new LoaderOptions() { LanguageLoaderOption.MasterLanguage() }`? Maybe the master language doesn't have any values for all your properties. But the name should have a value though. Instead of loading the content as OnSiteLinkBlock, you can load it as IContent and there you have the name property. Alternatively just cast OnSiteLinkBlock  to IContent after you have loaded it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically you use the `Items` or `FilteredItems` properties to read contents from ContentAreas. They return an enumerable of [ContentAreaItem](http://world.episerver.com/documentation/Class-library/?documentId=cms/7.5/1E110E9B)'s.

Resolve the IContent instance using an `IContentLoader` and feed it with the `ContentLink`

```
var loader = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentLoader>();

// contentarea is called UpperArea in the example
var icontentItems = currentPage.UpperArea
                         .FilteredItems
                         .Select(x => loader.Get<IContent>(x.ContentLink));

// example render in razor
foreach (var icontentItem in icontentItems)
{
    <h2>@icontentItem.Name</h2>
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is the solution! It works fine. I had searched the EPiServer documention before, but I couldn't find anything there. Many thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

In response to your question about alternatives to ContentAreas, the answer is yes. There are basically three ways of adding lists of block/page types, each one with its pros and cons:

```
- LinkItemCollection
- IList<ContentReference>
- ContentArea
```

This is a nice read about their main differences: https://gregwiechec.com/2015/09/comparing-list-properties/